# FFMPEG encoding issue with "mp42" video (conversion to H264 mp4)

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I am having problems encoding an "mp42" file to mp4 (H264) with the encoding options:

```
-vcodec libx264 -bufsize 32M -b:v 2800k -maxrate 3800k -g 63 -vf "scale=1280:720" -acodec aac -ab 192k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -strict experimental -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p"
```

Video file information:

```
Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2017-09-15T15:25:16.000000Z
  Duration: 01:28:40.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1479 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 2996 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-09-15T15:25:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
```

FFMPEG Encoding output is pasted below. For various reasons I cannot upgrade to a manual newer installation of ffmpeg but am using the Debian package version (Debian OS 9.1), with an ffmpeg that is quite recent.

Do people know what this problem is related to, and whether it has been solved in more recent ffmpeg versions?

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.7-1~deb9u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18) 20170516
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil 55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
libavcodec 57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
libavformat 57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
libavdevice 57. 1.100 / 57. 1.100
libavfilter 6. 65.100 / 6. 65.100
libavresample 3. 1. 0 / 3. 1. 0
libswscale 4. 2.100 / 4. 2.100
libswresample 2. 3.100 / 2. 3.100
libpostproc 54. 1.100 / 54. 1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/usr/local/shellscripte/markly/download-robert_k.mp4-1506570833-1506568923/robert_k.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand : mp42
minor_version : 0
compatible_brands: mp42mp41
creation_time : 2017-09-15T15:25:16.000000Z
Duration: 01:28:40.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3206 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 2996 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2017-09-15T15:25:16.000000Z
handler_name : Alias Data Handler
encoder : AVC Coding
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2017-09-15T15:25:16.000000Z
handler_name : Alias Data Handler
[libx264 @ 0x5620b118ec60] VBV buffer (32000) > level limit (14000)
[libx264 @ 0x5620b118ec60] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x5620b118ec60] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x5620b118ec60] 264 - core 148 r2748 97eaef2 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0 me=dia subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=22 lookahead_threads=5 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=63 keyint_min=6 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=2800 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=3800 vbv_bufsize=32000 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/usr/local/shellscripte/markly/output-robert_k.mp4-1506570833-1506568923/robert_k_720p.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand : mp42
minor_version : 0
compatible_brands: mp42mp41
encoder : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 2800 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2017-09-15T15:25:16.000000Z
handler_name : Alias Data Handler
encoder : Lavc57.64.101 libx264
Side data:
cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 3800000/0/2800000 buffer size: 32000000 vbv_delay: -1
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2017-09-15T15:25:16.000000Z
handler_name : Alias Data Handler
encoder : Lavc57.64.101 aac
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 124 fps=0.0 q=3.0 size= 205kB time=00:00:05.52 bitrate= 303.6kbits/s speed= 11x 
frame= 237 fps=237 q=24.0 size= 2801kB time=00:00:09.93 bitrate=2308.9kbits/s speed=9.94x 
frame= 356 fps=237 q=28.0 size= 4978kB time=00:00:14.74 bitrate=2765.9kbits/s speed=9.83x
......
......
......
frame=36564 fps=167 q=26.0 size= 534254kB time=00:24:23.13 bitrate=2991.3kbits/s speed=6.67x 
[h264 @ 0x5620b0bcdf80] Reference 3 >= 3
[h264 @ 0x5620b0bcdf80] error while decoding MB 38 33, bytestream 3005
[h264 @ 0x5620b0bcdf80] concealing 971 DC, 971 AC, 971 MV errors in B frame
[h264 @ 0x5620b08a2200] Invalid nal size 930990328
[h264 @ 0x5620b08a2200] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x5620b09490e0] Invalid nal size 1837326039
[h264 @ 0x5620b09490e0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x5620b0957020] Invalid nal size 187446698
[h264 @ 0x5620b0957020] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x5620b0aecf80] Invalid nal size 145353988
[h264 @ 0x5620b0aecf80] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x5620b0b08ae0] Invalid nal size -1036350434
[h264 @ 0x5620b0b08ae0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x5620b0dad3c0] Invalid nal size -1622171000
[h264 @ 0x5620b0dad3c0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Multiple frames in a packet.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] channel element 2.13 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] channel element 3.12 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Reserved bit set.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Prediction is not allowed in AAC-LC.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Number of bands (14) exceeds limit (5).
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Reserved bit set.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid argument
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Reserved bit set.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Number of scalefactor bands in group (57) exceeds limit (49).
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Reserved bit set.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Prediction is not allowed in AAC-LC.
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Remapped id too large
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list. (ffmpeg-devel@ffmpeg.org)
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Number of bands (3) exceeds limit (2).
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] channel element 3.8 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid argument
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] Remapped id too large
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x5620b118fa20] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp: //upload.ffmpeg.org/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list. (ffmpeg-devel@ffmpeg.org)
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome
```

Comment: Do you know if the input file actually plays?

Answer (score 0):

Since the output is showing decoding errors from 24min onwards you might have some corruption in the stream.
Have seen this before when streams are just welded together with different codecs.

You might be able to decode the first 24 minutes by limiting the decode time with specifying a duration for the input.

```
ffmpeg -t 24:23.13 -i <input> -vcodec libx264 -bufsize 32M -b:v 2800k -maxrate 3800k -g 63 -vf "scale=1280:720" -acodec aac -ab 192k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -strict experimental -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a regression of [Unable to decode some H.264 interlaced streams](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5529)

I downloaded 20180223 nightly build and the example file in the bug.  I see the same NAL errors :(